# Удалить атрибут HTML тега с помощью PHP

Tags: php

В тексте имеется разный вид ссылок
`http://www.example.ru/link`
`https://www.netsik.com/resource/`

**а не такой вид**

```
<a target="_blank" href="http://www.example.ru/link">ссылка</a>
```

---

Нашел такой код, но он удаляет только определенную ссылку.
Как сделать, чтобы все ссылки удаляло?

```
$html = preg_replace("|http://domain.ru|Uis", "#", $html);
```

Answer (score 2):

И зачем вам нужна пустая ссылка? Если не нужна, то посмотрите в сторону **strip_tags**

Comment: `strip_tags` удаляет все теги из строки, кроме разрешённых. Автор, скорее всего, имел ввиду весь текст как html, с другими тегами. Чтобы убрать ссылки, нужно прописывать все разрешённые теги. `$html = strip_tags($html, '<div><p><span>...')`

Answer (score 1):

```
$html = "
    <a target='_blank' href='http://www.example.ru/link'>ссылка 1</a>
    <a target='_blank' href='http://www.motherfucker.ru'>ссылка 2</a>
";

$html = preg_replace("!http(.*?)'!", "#'", $html);
```

Проверил, вроде работает

[image: ы]

Даже с атрибутами после ссылки

`<a target='_blank' href='http://www.example.ru/link' value='link'>ссылка 1</a>`

[image: ыы]